# XML parsing returns string with newlines

Tags: xml, go

I am trying to parse XML via the sitemap, and then loop over the address to get the details of the post in Go. But I am getting this weird error:

> : first path segment in URL cannot contain colon

This is the code snippet:

```
type SitemapIndex struct {
    Locations []Location `xml:"sitemap"`
}

type Location struct {
    Loc string `xml:"loc"`
}

func (l Location) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(l.Loc)
}

func main() {
    resp, _ := http.Get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/index.xml")
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    var s SitemapIndex
    xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)
    for _, Location := range s.Locations {
        fmt.Printf("Location: %s", Location.Loc)
        resp, err := http.Get(Location.Loc)
        fmt.Println("resp", resp)
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Location: 
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml
resp <nil>
err parse 
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml
: first path segment in URL cannot contain colon
Location: 
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/opinions.xml
resp <nil>
err parse 
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/opinions.xml
: first path segment in URL cannot contain colon
...
...
```

My guess is that the `Location.Loc` returns a new line before and after the actuall address.
Eg: `\nLocation: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml\n`

Because hardcoding the URL works as expected:

```
for _, Location := range s.Locations {
        fmt.Printf("Location: %s", Location.Loc)
        test := "https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml"
        resp, err := http.Get(test)
        fmt.Println("resp", resp)
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }
```

Output, as you can see the error is nil:

```
Location: 
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml
resp &{200 OK 200 HTTP/2.0 2 0 map[Server:[nginx] Arc-Service:[api] Arc-Org-Name:[washpost] Expires:[Sat, 02 Feb 2019 05:32:38 GMT] Content-Security-Policy:[upgrade-insecure-requests] Arc-Deployment:[washpost] Arc-Organization:[washpost] Cache-Control:[private, max-age=60] Arc-Context:[index] Arc-Application:[Feeds] Vary:[Accept-Encoding] Content-Type:[text/xml; charset=utf-8] Arc-Servername:[api.washpost.arcpublishing.com] Arc-Environment:[index] Arc-Org-Env:[washpost] Arc-Route:[/feeds] Date:[Sat, 02 Feb 2019 05:31:38 GMT]] 0xc000112870 -1 [] false true map[] 0xc00017c200 0xc0000ca370}
err <nil>
Location: 
...
...
```

But I am very new to Go, and so I have no idea what's wrong. Could you please tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right indeed, the issue comes from the newlines. As you can see, you are using `Printf` without adding any `\n` and one is added at the beginning and one at the end in the output.

You can use [`strings.Trim`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Trim) to remove those newlines. Here is [an example](https://goplay.space/#yLpX1NTY3dJ) working with the sitemap that you are trying to parse. Once the string is trimmed, you will be able to call `http.Get` on it without any errors.

```golang
func main() {
    var s SitemapIndex
    xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)

    for _, Location := range s.Locations {
        loc := strings.Trim(Location.Loc, "\n")
        fmt.Printf("Location: %s\n", loc)
    }
}
```

This code properly outputs the locations without any newlines, as expected:

```golang
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/opinions.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/local.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/sports.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/national.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/world.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/business.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/technology.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/lifestyle.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/entertainment.xml
Location: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/goingoutguide.xml
```

The reason why you have those newlines in the `Location.Loc` field is because of the XML returned by this URL. Entries are following this form:

```xml
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/goingoutguide.xml
</loc>
</sitemap>
```

And as you can see, there are newlines before and after the content within the `loc` elements.

Comment: `newlines before and after the content within the loc elements.`! That was it!

Answer (score 1):

See the comments embedded in the modified code to describe and fix the issue

```
func main() {
    resp, _ := http.Get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/index.xml")
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    var s SitemapIndex
    xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)
    for _, Location := range s.Locations {
            // Note that %v shows that there are indeed newlines at beginning and end of Location.Loc
            fmt.Printf("Location: (%v)", Location.Loc)
            // solution: use strings.TrimSpace to remove newlines from Location.Loc
            resp, err := http.Get(strings.TrimSpace(Location.Loc))
            fmt.Println("resp", resp)
            fmt.Println("err", err)
    }
```

}